# Craps game probability

Tags: probability, dice

Given 1 roll in a game of craps, a win is if, the sum of outcomes on a fair pair 
of dice is 7 or 11, otherwise you are said to crap-out . Compute the probability 
of a win on just 1 roll? Im second guessing myself on my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you will be able to obtain the answer by adding the probability of rolling a 7 with two dice and the probability of rolling an 11 with 2 dice.

Therefore:  $P_7 + P_{11}= \frac{1}{6}+ \frac{1}{18}$ $= \frac{2}{9}$

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have a red die and a green die.  Each can come up $6$ ways, so there are $6^2=36$ possible rolls.  How many sum to $7$?  How many sum to $11$?

Comment: 3/36+ 1/36= 4/36...reduced fraction 2/9....Thank you so much.